# Are there any ways to purchase the 3DS Nintendo ambassador games?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

According to [The Nintendo 3DS Ambassador Program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_3DS#Nintendo_3DS_Ambassador_Program)

> "there were no plans to make the Game Boy Advance Ambassador titles similarly available"

This article is (at time of posting) a little under a year old, is this still the case? Will these sets of games ever be available for the 3DS without being an ambassador?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this point, none of the GBA Ambassador games are released. There are a few of the NES releases that have hit the eshop for general purchase - Super Mario Bros, Donkey Kong Jr., The Legend of Zelda, Metroid, NES Open Tournament Golf, and Legend of Zelda II (to be released in November).

As of yet, the GBA games have not been released, and it doesn't appear that they will be any time soon - according to [this press release](http://www.nintendoworldreport.com/news/31999), they are concentrating on Game Boy, Game Boy Color, and NES titles for now.

Nintendo may decide at a later date to add GBA titles for download (as they did with a few Game Gear titles), but as of this time, it doesn't appear that they have any plans to do so any time in the near future, choosing instead to focus on first party titles for the 3DS such as Paper Mario, Luigi's Mansion, etc, and VC titles from older systems that predate the GBA.

Comment: Which is a damn shame because the GBA's library is amazing.

Comment: The funny thing is that the emulator they're using works flawlessly -- it's fantastic.  If they a) let you purchase the Ambassador Program GBA games and b) added wifi-based Link Cable emulation, I'd buy my kids each a 3DS just to play Kirby and the Amazing Mirror together.  It's that good.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you can't directly buy them from the 3DS eShop. You can still buy a used Ambassador 3DS, transfer all those games to your 3DS, and then sell the extra 3DS.

If you don't wanna lose your StreePass data, you can transfer your 3DS profile into the Ambassador one, wait for the system transfer cooldown to finish (one week), and then transfer the merged profiles back into your original 3DS.